# Minesweeper algorithm that works within O(1) space complexity

Tags: java, algorithm, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search, minesweeper

For minesweeper algorithm, instead of the most obvious BFS or DFS solution, I want a O(1) space solution.

First of all, I'll explain how the program works. I will pass in a 2D array, with 1 represent mine and 0 represent blank space. The program return true if the map can be opened with single click. Return false if it cannot. Example:

```
0, 0, 0, 1, 0
0, 1, 1, 1, 1
0, 0, 0, 0, 1
0, 1, 1, 0, 1
0, 0, 1, 0, 1 

should return false

0, 0, 0, 0, 0
0, 1, 1, 1, 1
0, 0, 0, 0, 1
0, 1, 1, 0, 1
0, 0, 1, 0, 1 

should return true
```

My algorithm is to visit each 0s and mark as 2. Than from that point, I continue to visit all the 0s and mark as 2. When there's no more 0s, I will visit 2s and then mark 2s as 3s. In the end, all 0s should be marked as 3 if they are inter-connected. Example:

```
0, 0, 1
0, 1, 1
0, 0, 1
   |
   v
2, 0, 1
0, 1, 1
0, 0, 1
   |
   v
2, 2, 1
0, 1, 1
0, 0, 1
   |
   v
2, 3, 1
0, 1, 1
0, 0, 1
   |
   v
2, 3, 1
2, 1, 1
0, 0, 1
   |
   v
2, 3, 1
2, 1, 1
2, 0, 1
   |
   v
2, 3, 1
2, 1, 1
2, 2, 1
   |
   v
2, 3, 1
2, 1, 1
2, 3, 1
   |
   v
2, 3, 1
2, 1, 1
3, 3, 1
   |
   v
2, 3, 1
3, 1, 1
3, 3, 1
   |
   v
3, 3, 1
3, 1, 1
3, 3, 1
   |
   v
return true, since there's no more 0 in the graph
```

This is my code followed by 3 test cases. Kindly help me review the coding structure/styles or tell me if I have considered all possible test cases. Thanks!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MineSweeperAlgorithm {

    // this minesweeper algorithm uses O(1) space complexity

    // set verbose to false to hide the step-by-step loggging
    private static final boolean verbose = true;
    private static int stepCount = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MineSweeperAlgorithm ins = new MineSweeperAlgorithm();

        int[][] matrix;
        // make a test case
        stepCount = 1;
        matrix = new int[5][];
        matrix[0] = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 1, 0};
        matrix[1] = new int[]{0, 1, 1, 1, 1};
        matrix[2] = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 1};
        matrix[3] = new int[]{0, 1, 1, 0, 1};
        matrix[4] = new int[]{0, 0, 1, 0, 1};

        // run the test
        System.out.println("Result is " +
                ins.validate(matrix, matrix.length, matrix[0].length));
        System.out.println();

        // make another test case
        stepCount = 1;
        matrix = new int[5][];
        matrix[0] = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 1, 0};
        matrix[1] = new int[]{0, 1, 0, 1, 0};
        matrix[2] = new int[]{0, 1, 0, 1, 0};
        matrix[3] = new int[]{0, 1, 0, 1, 0};
        matrix[4] = new int[]{0, 1, 0, 0, 0};

        // run the test
        System.out.println("Result is " +
                ins.validate(matrix, matrix.length, matrix[0].length));
        System.out.println();

        // make another test case
        stepCount = 1;
        matrix = new int[5][];
        matrix[0] = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 1, 0};
        matrix[1] = new int[]{0, 1, 1, 1, 0};
        matrix[2] = new int[]{0, 1, 0, 1, 0};
        matrix[3] = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 1, 0};
        matrix[4] = new int[]{0, 1, 0, 0, 0};

        // run the test
        System.out.println("Result is " +
                ins.validate(matrix, matrix.length, matrix[0].length));
        System.out.println();
    }

    public boolean validate(int[][] matrix, int m, int n) {
        Pos nextStep = findZero(matrix, m, n);
        if (nextStep == null) {
            // the matrix deos not contain 0
            return false;
        }

        // visit the first position, and go from there
        matrix[nextStep.x][nextStep.y] = 2;
        while (nextStep != null) {
            nextStep = step(matrix, nextStep, m, n);
        }

        // after visiting all positions, check if there is remaining 0s
        return findZero(matrix, m, n) == null;
    }

    Pos step(int[][] matrix, Pos cur, int m, int n) {
        // Now cur is located at a pos with value = 2
        // print matrix in "verbose" mode
        if (verbose) {
            System.out.println("Step #" + stepCount++);
            for (int[] array : matrix) {
                for (int num : array) {
                    System.out.print(num + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        // make a list of valid neighbors, for the convenience of checking
        List<Pos> neighbors = new ArrayList<Pos>();
        neighbors.add(new Pos(cur.x - 1, cur.y));
        neighbors.add(new Pos(cur.x + 1, cur.y));
        neighbors.add(new Pos(cur.x, cur.y - 1));
        neighbors.add(new Pos(cur.x, cur.y + 1));
        for (int i = neighbors.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (!isValidPos(neighbors.get(i), m, n)) {
                neighbors.remove(i);
            }
        }

        // check if there is adjacent 0,
        // if there is, mark 0 as 2 and return that position
        for (Pos neighbor : neighbors) {
            if (matrix[neighbor.x][neighbor.y] == 0) {
                matrix[neighbor.x][neighbor.y] = 2;
                return neighbor;
            }
        }

        // if no adjacent 0, then check if there is adjacent 2.
        // if there is, mark current as 3 and then return that position
        for (Pos neighbor : neighbors) {
            if (matrix[neighbor.x][neighbor.y] == 2) {
                matrix[cur.x][cur.y] = 3;
                return neighbor;
            }
        }

        //if no adjacent 0 and no adjacent 2, mark current as 3 and return null
        matrix[cur.x][cur.y] = 3;
        return null;
    }

    boolean isValidPos(Pos p, int m, int n) {
        return p.x >= 0 && p.x < m && p.y >= 0 && p.y < n;
    }

    Pos findZero(int[][] matrix, int m, int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (matrix[i][j] == 0) {
                    return new Pos(i, j);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    class Pos {
        int x;
        int y;

        public Pos(int a, int b) {
            x = a;
            y = b;
        }
    }
}
```

The code is also available online for viewing or checking execution result at http://ideone.com/wmryWn

Comment: The examples above are not opened with a single click. All cells with a 0 have mines as neighbors, are not labelled 0 and therefore do not trigger an "open all neighbors".

Comment: It seems as if you are solving a graph connectivity problem or even a "flood fill" problem.  But I wouldn't exactly call it a minesweeper problem because the standard minesweeper game doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 3):

### Bug

Your program failed with this input:

```
        matrix[0] = new int[]{0, 0, 1, 1, 1};
        matrix[1] = new int[]{0, 1, 1, 1, 1};
        matrix[2] = new int[]{0, 1, 0, 0, 1};
        matrix[3] = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 1};
        matrix[4] = new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0, 1};
```

You can [see the result here at ideone](http://ideone.com/3MZ2jo).

The reason for the failure is that your backtracking (following the 2's) is susceptible to running itself into a dead end.  I'm not convinced that you can ever get your current method to work for all test cases.

### Is it really O(1) space?

Since you are storing integers into your matrix, I'm not sure I would call that an O(1) space solution.  If you stored a direction into each cell as you passed through it, you could easily implement a DFS that way.  So I believe your solution is really O(N) space.

Comment: You're right. The test case won't pass because the traverse goes into a dead-end. Thanks very much for pointing out! I will check my code in a while.

Comment: About O(1) space, I mean the extra space used in the algorithm is only the "List<Pos> neighbors" wihch is only 4 item. The 2D matrix is given as input, so it's not counted as a space usage. Let me know your thoughts!